# Adding icon with my overflow menu features

Tags: java, android, oncreateoptionsmenu

I have a fetch function and I'm trying to call it in `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)` for filling the menu in real time.
This function is working perfectly in the overflow menu but is not working in my `switch` block. I'm trying to call this function properly and run it when clicked on my new icon. Any idea?

```
private void fetchMembers(Menu menu) {
    @Override
    public void onNext(ListMembersResponse response) {
        if (response.members != null && !response.members.isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < response.members.size(); i++) {
               Merchant merchant = response.members.get(i);
               menu.add( Menu.NONE, i, Menu.NONE, merchant.firstName + " " + merchant.lastName);    ///here is fetching full name
            }
        }
    }
```

My `switch` block:

```
switch (item.getItemId())
{
    case R.id.menu_item_filter:
    fetchMembers(menu);

    case R.id.menu_item_search:

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getTitle())) {
        trackEvent(AnalyticsManager.CATEGORY_HISTORY_SEARCH, 
                          AnalyticsManager.ACTION_TRIGGERED,
                          AnalyticsManager.LABEL_TRIGGERED);
        String newText = String.valueOf(item.getTitle());
        String text = newText.trim().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

        return true;
    } else {
        paymentsAdapter.filter("");
        itemManager.expandGroup(0);
        scrollListener.setEndlessScrollEnabled(true);
        return true;
    }
}

return false;  //true
```

**P.S:** I've tried to change my overflow icon with another one with:

```
Drawable drawable = 
    ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.change_pass);
toolbar.setOverflowIcon(drawable);
```

but it is not working either. The error is a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Is it Ok now? Sorry about that, thank you for recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED
   firstly created a function from my basefragment

```
  @Override
  public void updateToolbar(Toolbar toolbar) {

 setTitle( R.string.title_transaction_history );
 Drawable drawablew =
 ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_icon_filter);
 toolbar.setOverflowIcon(drawablew);
}
```

Then it is works for me.